# Selenium WebDriver getText()

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, gettext

Using Selenium WebDriver .getText() function in Java, I'm trying to access some text without any positive results. Is not even in the WebElement object. The text I want to fetch is: "eNewsletter Sign Up"

The HTML code from where I am fetching this looks like this:

```
<a class="footer" href="/contact/email-sign-up/" onclick="aloneTracking('footerEmailSignUp')">eNewsletter Sign Up</a>
```

And the Java code looks like this:

```
     List<WebElement> idElemList = driver.findElements(By.className("footer"));

    System.out.println(idElemList.size());
    String str = "";
    if (idElemList.size() > 0) {
        WebElement firstElement = idElemList.get(0);
        str = firstElement.toString();
        System.out.println("**** : " + str);
        str = firstElement.getText();
        System.out.println("¨¨" + str);
    }
```

In the first System.out.println() I get that the list is nine elements long.

In the second:

```
<a onclick="aloneTracking('footerEmailSignUp')" href="/contact/email-sign-up/" class="footer">
```

In the third:

```
<a onclick="aloneTracking('footerEmailSignUp')" href="/contact/email-sign-up/" class="footer">
```

How can I get that text?

Comment: You're getting a list of 9 elements, but then you're only trying `getText()` on the first one. Are you sure that's the right element? Have you tried the other 8?

Comment: Actually, I need to get all 9 elements and I have the same problem on the rest of the elements.  
I just took the first element as an example. I really don't understand why I am not able to get that text. If I run the same code on another web-page of the same web-site, using the same template, it works. 
What I think is weird too, is that if I do element.toString() not even then the text will show up.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to find the element by link text and call getText on that element

By.ByLinkText   By.ByPartialLinkText

Comment: I tried to find the element through By.linkText but it didn't work.
It's like the text is not there.

Comment: Anyone that knows, please help?
I'm still facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the second and the third is the value of the String `str` after doing:

Second:

```
firstElement = idElemList.get(0);
str = firstElement.toString();
System.out.println("xxxx : " + str);
```

Result of System.out.println:

```
 xxxx : <a onclick="aloneTracking('footerEmailSignUp')" href="/contact/email-sign-up/" class="footer">
```

**Third:**

```
WebElement firstElement = idElemList.get(0);
str = firstElement.getText();
System.out.println("¨¨ : " + str);
```

Result of System.out.println:

```
¨¨ : <a onclick="aloneTracking('footerEmailSignUp')" href="/contact/email-sign-up/" class="footer">
```